# SSO implementation using SALM 2.0 SOAP binding

Tags: spring, soap, spring-security, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am trying to add SSO functionality in my existing web application. Requirement is to use SOAP Binding with SAML 2.0, I am able to read SAML response using HTTP-POST binding but i want to read SAML response using SOAP binding. Please let me know if anyone has already used SAML SOAP Binding for SSO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SP-Initiated SSO: POST/Artifact Bindings

Comment: Thanks you. Adding more- for SP initiated SSO, mostly Profile:Browser is used, which does not support SOAP Binding.